# How to : Fix UIApplication open URL Method in App Delegate

Tags: swift, url, appdelegate

```
 func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
        PlayPortalAuthClient.shared.open(url: url)
        return true
    }
```

The method above isn't being called anymore when passed its url data.. Is anyone aware of an IOS 13 change / or an update to this method? I need suggestions on how to get it working again... Right now it doesn't function.

Comment: Assuming you have not completely opted out of using scenes, implement the corresponding UISceneDelegate method.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you that worked!